# How to set TextStyle of PagerTabStrip to Bold?

Tags: android, styles, android-viewpager

I'm using `PagerTabStrip` in `ViewPager` to show the title of each page. Here is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textColor="#a4c639"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set the textStyle to bold in `PagerTabStrip` like this:
`android:textStyle="bold"`. But this is not possible in `PagerTabStrip`. Seems like it has only `textcolor` property for text. What is the way by which I can set the style to bold?

Comment: What do you have in `@style/TitleStripTextAppearance`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh I forgot to remove this line at the time of posting the question. I was trying to add style in `@style/TitleStripTextAppearance` but I'm not sure will this work or not?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What you need to do is create a style for the text, and then use the android:textAppearance attribute...

Perhaps something like this:

```
 <style name="PagerTabStripText">
      <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#a4c639</item>
 </style>
```

And then in your PagerTabStrip XML do this:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" 
        android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStripText"/>
```

Comment: By the way, eclipse doesnt autosuggest android:textAppearance inside android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip. But dont be confused by that, textAppearance works for PagerTabStrip.

Comment: I need to use custom typeface for my pagertabstrip. Any idea how to use that?

Comment: @Justin - `textMultiLine` property is not working in this way. Any other way around?

Comment: Any idea on how one specifically styles the center tab title? As in, the user's current tab title would be bold and the others be normal?

Comment: android studio doesnt have textAppearance

Answer (score 4):

PagerTabStrip doesn't aceppts textAppearance.

Like @Justin said above, but on xml put:

`style="@style/PagerTabStripText"`

not:

`android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStripText"`

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to style the center tab title differently from the others, then you'll need to use reflection:

```
try {
    final Class pagerTitleStripClass = PagerTitleStrip.class;
    final Field mCurrTextField = pagerTitleStripClass.getDeclaredField("mCurrText");
    mCurrTextField.setAccessible(true);

    // mTitle is my class's PagerTabStrip member variable
    final TextView mCurrText = (TextView) mCurrTextField.get(mTitle);
    mCurrText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Exception when styling currently selected title!", e);
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution is subject to potentially not working anymore when updates for the [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) are released (as that's where the [PagerTitleStrip](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) class is from). In particular, this code sample is working with [revision 20](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions).

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend using reflection for these kind of "tricks". There is a reason it is private - It may change at any time - even during different commits of the same revision.

Reflection should be used for meta-level-stuff like writing frameworks, and such.